# Inject ADO env variables in the script inside the same ADO build pipeline

Tags: azure, maven, azure-pipelines

I have a use-case that calls into code, that calls some other code, and the other code needs the ADO environment variable (of the same ADO pipeline) where it is being executed

The question is - how do I inject these ADO pipe environment variables inside that code?

More Details::

1. I'm Dockerizing a Java app, which takes input from an 2 entrypoint.sh files
2. the 1st input files downloads a customized plugin
3. the 2nd input files executes the plugin (download in step2) & inserts a new JSON code section in pom.xml
4. the inserted JSON code section uses ADO build variables $(Build.DefinitionName) & $(Build.SourceBranchName)
5. 'mvn package' then should use the updated pom.xml (with ADO variables) to build the application

My ADO pipeline completes successfully (with docker build task finishing properly), but the ADO Environment Variable does'nt bring in the 'value' of the variables but $(Build.DefinitionName) & $(SourceBranchName) as outputs.

The JSON code that is to be inserted in POM.xml

```
"createBuildSessionId": true,
"appName": "$(Build.DefinitionName)",
"branchName": "$(Build.SourceBranchName)",
"buildName": "$(Build.BuildNumber)",
"packagesIncluded": "*com.m*.*"
```

The actual logs once ADO Build pipe is executed:

```
<configuration>
<createBuildSessionId>true</createBuildSessionId>
<appName>$(Build.DefinitionName)</appName>
<build>$(Build.BuildNumber)</build>
<branch>$(Build.SourceBranchName)</branch>
<packagesincluded>*com.m*.*</packagesincluded>
```

Any help would be highly appreciated !!

Comment: You could refer to the answer and check if it could give you some help. And you can help me determine whether your json code is a separate file or is encoded in the dockerfile. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are dockerizing a Java app, you could try the following steps to pass the Pipeline Variables to the Pom.xml file.

1. Import pipeline variables into dockerfile through docker ARG
2. Use the imported variable in the mvn package command and pass it as a parameter to Pom.xml

`mvn  package -DmyVariable=someValue`

Here is my example:

Dockerfile

```
ARG BranchName
ARG BuildNumber
ARG BuildDefinition

ENV BranchName=${BranchName}
ENV BuildNumber = ${BuildNumber}
ENV BuildDefinition = ${BuildDefinition}



RUN mvn package -DBuild.DefinitionName=$BuildDefinition  -DBuild.SourceBranchName=$BranchName -DBuild.BuildNumber=$BuildNumber
```

Build Pipeline

```
  - task: Docker@2
    displayName: build
    inputs:
      containerRegistry: Dockerconnection
      command: build
      arguments: --build-arg BranchName="$(Build.SourceBranchName)"   --build-arg BuildNumber="$(Build.BuildNumber)"  --build-arg BuildDefinition="$(Build.DefinitionName)"
```

Json Code

```
"createBuildSessionId": true,
"appName": "${Build.DefinitionName}",
"branchName": "${Build.SourceBranchName}",
"buildName": "${Build.BuildNumber}",
"packagesIncluded": "*com.m*.*"
```